# Suppressing the newline when entering an environment

Tags: formatting, line-breaking, verbatim

Is there anyway to suppress the newline that is inserted when beginning an environment?  For example, I would like

```
\noindent{\bf 1.}\begin{verbatim}some code\end{verbatim}
```

to appear as a single line.

(`\verb` doesn't seem to look quite as nice as the `verbatim` environment).

Comment: If you want inline verbatim, then `\verb` is what should be used. If the code is on multiple lines, you should tell.

Answer (score 6):

Use a correct list for your numbering instead of `\noindent \bf 1.`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[font=\bfseries]
\item
\begin{verbatim}
abc
aba
\end{verbatim}

\item blublb
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]